# jQuery e.target with a $(document).on("click", function(e)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that closes the `.modal` when the user clicks away anywhere on `document` except for the modal.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal, .icon-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

The problem is that the `fontawesome` icon interferes with the `.button` target that opens the modal and the click zone is only the `.button` and not anything that is nested inside (the icon).

How do I change the function so that the modal opens even if the icon is clicked, and then loses it's `.active` class when the user clicks away?

```js
$("[data-close]").click(function(e) {
  const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
  const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length ?
    $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]') :
    $(dataClose);
  if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.removeClass("active");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).prop("id");
  $(".modal").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal, .icon-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#icon {
  color: silver;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button" id="google" data-close="google" />
  <img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
  <div class="button" id="icon" data-close="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal icon-modal" data-id="icon">
  <div class="header">Icon</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're exactly trying to do. Font Awesome does not interrupt the click event. I would consider using jQuery UI as well.

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-close]").click(function(e) {
    const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
    const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length ?
      $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]') :
      $(dataClose);
    if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
      elem.removeClass("active");
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  });

  $("body").not(".active").click(function(e) {
    console.log("body click");
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
  });

  $(".button").click(function(e) {
    var el = $(".modal[data-id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']");
    console.log($(this).attr("id") + " clicked, remove class 'active' from all. Add 'active' to ", el);
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    el.addClass("active");
    console.log(el);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#icon {
  color: silver;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button" id="google" data-close="google" />
  <img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
  <div class="button" id="icon" data-close="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-id="icon">
  <div class="header">Icon</div>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see here that I have adjusted the `click` callback. If you're not creating dynamic content, I would use `.click()` versus `.on()`.

In this case, it may be best to remove `active` class from all then add it to the specific one element. `.toggleClass()` will do this, yet depending on the state of your script you may get varied results or unexpected results.

Making use of the right selector can also help a lot. Since we're targeting a specific `.modal` that has a `data-id` attribute, we can use `$(".modal[data-id='icon']")` as the selector to get that specific element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that now if I click away, the icon modal doesn't disappear like it does when I open the apple modal and click away. I'm having trouble being able to click the icon itself to open the icon modal, then being able to click away and have that modal close like it does for apple

Comment: @KyleUnderhill see updated code. Again, might consider using jQuery UI Dialogs.

Comment: Better but the reason I had 

$(".apple-modal, .icon-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");

is so that the google modal (and any other modal that isn't apple and icon) doesn't close on click away. The idea is that some close when clicked away and other modals remain open unless the button is pressed again. My issue was that for the modals that close on click away, I couldn't click the icon to open the modal, only the target button...

Comment: @KyleUnderhill I am not able to understand the logic you're trying to use. Perhaps you can solve that on your own. Your post was about button click was not targeting the right modal element. So if my post addresses that, hope you want to mark it as the answer.